# Sql how to switch tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, switch-statement, multiple-tables

I have two tables one of them have historical(**cdr_hist**) data other table have data from today(**cdr_stage**).  My script must run every 30 minutes and calculate data from last 4 hours but every night at 12 all data move at **cdr_hist**.

The question is how I can switch and take data from history table when script run at 12:00 because  **cdr_stage** is empty...
I tried this:

```
IF  OBJECT_ID   ('[**CDR_Stage**]') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    Select.....
    From **CDR_Stage**
END
ELSE
    Select.....
    From **CDR_Hist**
END
```

But its not work correctly...
Any ideas??

Comment: _But its not work correctly_ What does that mean?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it actually work but not calculated all data. i lose rows between 11:30 pm and 12:30 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the record existence instead of table existence

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   CDR_Stage)
  SELECT *
  FROM   CDR_Stage
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM   CDR_Hist
```

Or Dynamic Sql

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)

SET @sql = 'select * from '
           + CASE
               WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   CDR_Stage) THEN 'CDR_Stage'
               ELSE 'CDR_Hist'
             END

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for IFs , that can be done with pure sql using `UNION` and `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM CDR_Stage
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CDR_Hist
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CDR_Stage) -- Second select will return data only if first one won't .
```